# Evaluation metric for prediction interval?

Tags: prediction-interval, quantile-regression

In quantile regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression), what are some suitable evaluation metrics?

Intuitively, I think a good model should have:

- good accuracy, i.e. the prediction interval (say at 90% confidence) should contain the true value of `y`.
- narrow width, i.e. the interval should not be large (if we expand the interval to `[-Inf, Inf]` definitely this interval will cover the true of `y`).

Could you recommend some ways to evaluate a predictor that outputs the prediction interval?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

- picp pinaw
- quantile scores
- winkler score